# Change controller animator and sprite renderer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

How do I allow the user enable via a simple button "use" change the animator controller & sprite renderer?

After he buy a new skin to character, he clicks "use", and when he enters the game, the skin is enabled.

I already have 5 ready animator controller (Bee1, Bee2, Bee3, Bee4) and the Bee as defaut.

The sprites renders are ready (Bee1_0, Bee2_0, Bee3_0, Bee4_0) and Bee_0 as default.

Please C# if possible (Using Unity3D)

Below the script player if necessary

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;

public class Bee : MonoBehaviour {

    public float moveSpeed;

    public Transform bee;
    private Animator animator;

    public bool isGrounded = true;
    public float force;

    public float jumpTime = 0.1f;
    public float jumpDelay = 0.1f;
    public bool jumped = false;
    public Transform ground;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        animator = bee.GetComponent<Animator> ();
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        Move ();


    }


    void Move ()
    {

        isGrounded = Physics2D.Linecast (this.transform.position, ground.position, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer ("Floor"));
        animator.SetFloat ("runB", Mathf.Abs (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis ("Horizontal")));
        if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal") > 0) {

            transform.Translate (Vector2.right * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector2 (0, 0);
        }
        if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal") < 0) {

            transform.Translate (Vector2.right * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector2 (0, 180);
        }

        if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown ("Vertical") && isGrounded && !jumped) {

            //  rigidbody2D.AddForce (transform.up * force);
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().AddForce (transform.up * force);
            jumpTime = jumpDelay;
            animator.SetTrigger ("jumpB");
            jumped = true;
        }

        jumpTime -= Time.deltaTime;

        if (jumpTime <= 0 && isGrounded && jumped) {

            animator.SetTrigger ("groundB");
            jumped = false;
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [RuntimeAnimatorController](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RuntimeAnimatorController.html). Didn't test the code, but the usage is

```
animator = bee.GetComponent< Animator >();
animator.runtimeAnimatorController = Resources.Load("Bee1") as RuntimeAnimatorController;
//or:
RuntimeAnimatorController animator = (RuntimeAnimatorController)RuntimeAnimatorController.Instantiate(Resources.Load("Bee1", typeof(RuntimeAnimatorController)));
bee.GetComponent< Animator >().runtimeAnimatorController = animator;
```

But if I was you I'd create prefab for all bee types and swap out them on a parent "player game object" when the player bought the new thing and it's time to apply the change.
Bigger (in file size) but it is safer (you see how it works before run-time, Unity can optimize it as it's a prefab, can fix it up if has glitches for some reason, can bake things up, etc), might also be somewhat faster (especially if you cache the different bee types, in case the change can be rapid).